# Terminate Powershell Function any error Comes

Tags: powershell

I am writing a powershell script in which there are multiple function are there, and I want to terminate the function if any error comes in between without going to next function.

My Code:

```
    function A
    { 
        Write-Host "A Block Started" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    }
    
    function B
    {    
        $master_key = facter -p dev_master_key
        $pwd = facter -p certificate_pwd
        $scriptPath = "$PSScriptRoot\script.sql"

Invoke-Sqlcmd -InputFile "$scriptPath"
    
    }
    
    function C
    { 
        Write-Host "C Block Started" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    }
    
    function D
    { 
        Write-Host "D Block Started" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    }
    
    $stamp = Get-Date -UFormat "%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S"
    Start-Transcript "C:\temp\script-$ENV-$stamp.log"
    $start = Get-Date
    
    A
    B
    C
    D
    
    $end = Get-Date
    $totaltime = $end - $start
    Write-Host "`nTime Elapsed: $($totaltime.tostring("hh\:mm\:ss"))" -ForegroundColor red -BackgroundColor white
    Stop-Transcript
```

In Function I am trying to change the content of file then triggering the script, if any error comes in script it will show the error and moves to next function which I don't want, I want to terminate the script there itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop" should work